# Unity ragdoll issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

the issue that I have is enemy ragdoll interacting with the Player and sending it up into the air. so here is what's happening:

player kills NPC
NPC dies and ragdolls
player walks over ragdoll and bounces all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but from what I'm understanding when player or other objects collide with ragdoll, then ragdoll thrown violently around. In that case you can simply increase the mass of your ragdoll rigidbodies. Somthing like this:

```
private void SetRagdollWeight(float weight)
{
    Rigidbody[] rigidbodies = GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rigidbodies.Length; i++)
    {
        rigidbodies[i].mass = weight;
    }
}
```

The higher the weight, The harder it gets for ragdoll to bounce around.